# SAML 2.0 - Authentication issue instant is too old or in the future

Tags: saml-2.0, pac4j

I have an authentication service with SAML. I've recently had a weird issue saying that `Authentication issue instant is too old or in the future`. The maximum lifetime in the backend is set up to 1 hour. I tried reproducing the issue with no luck and I don't know what the root cause of this problem might be.

Comment: have you checked the server time?

Comment: I increased in the max lifetime to 1 day and this works fine by now.

Answer (score 2):

In WebSSOProfileConusumerImpl set the property “setMaximumAuthenticationLifetime“ to maximum like greater value.
or match with your IDP session expiry time. It would solve the problem.

The default value is 7200 seconds which is two hours.

Comment: Could you please quote the source or a reference to the default value of 2 hours?